# What is the difference between EdgeNGramTokenizer and EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is the only difference between them is that EdgeNGramTokenizer acts on the input text (after processed by the charFilter) and EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2 acts on the tokens generated by the tokenizer?

If that is the case, can we say that even some tokenFilters generate more strings from the tokens? (ex: Ngrams generated after using EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2) and can the new strings generated be called tokens ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to tell for sure is to set up a request that call the Test Analyzer API, passing in an input string and a custom analyzer that has the tokenizer and filters that you want. The output is all of the tokens produced by the analyzer, for the given input. The Test Analyzer API needs a search index on the URL, but the API doesn't actually iterate over the index, so really you could specify any valid index and then enter whatever term inputs you want.